# jquery ie explorer can not load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer

IE Do not work, how to fix the load() function in all my Jquery code? 
I try many options to get it work. (I us IE 11 last version)

**Like change this**

```
$('#tickets_table').load('tickets.php');
```

**to this**

```
$('#tickets_table').load('tickets.php'+ Math.random());
```

But still not work

```
$(this).ready(function () {

    function InfoUp() {
        var stat = ["game_id_next", "game_id"];
        var url = "keno_script.php";

        $.each(stat, function (i, key) {
            $.post(url, {
                stats: key
            }, function (data) {
                $("#" + key).html(data);
            });
        });
    }

    setInterval(InfoUp, 1000);

    $('#table_for_balls').load('keno_balls.php');
    $('#tickets_table').load('tickets.php');
    $('#ostalos').load('mymoney.php');

    $('#ticket').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var datastring = $("#ticket").serialize();
        $('#tickets_place').html('Данные билета отправляються..');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'submit.php',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            data: datastring,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#tickets_table').html(data).load('tickets.php');
                $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
                $('#ostalos').load('mymoney.php');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks for help.

**Edited**

**The second problem:** In this function, when (data == "00:00") , nothing happend in IE, what not good now?

Thanks

```
function InfoTime() {
    var stat = ['table_for_timer'];
    var url = "keno_script.php?" + Math.random();
    $.each(stat, function (i, key) {
        $.post(url, {
            cache: false, stats: key
        }, function (data) {
            if (data == "00:00") {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'keno_balls.php?' + Math.random(),
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    //data: '',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#table_for_balls').html(data);
                        $('#tickets_table').load('tickets.php?'+ Math.random());
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
            $("#" + key).html(data);
        });
    });
}
setInterval(InfoTime, 1000);
```

Comment: Try with a question mark `('tickets.php?'+ Math.random());`

Comment: lol, with add simple ? it work ))) Thanks! I will continue check all code

Comment: when a file is in ie cache, the $.load() isn't trigger, so with this function you just prevent ie from caching the file ;)

Comment: yes @ekans, i hate the IE, but need for people ))) My choice is Chrome or Opera )))

Comment: @Anton I add second problem, maybe u know and can help ? )

Comment: did you try to `console.log` data?

Comment: @EaterOfCode yes, still not work in IE (((

Comment: `console.log` outputs the data in the console so you see what is in the data value

Comment: @EaterOfCode nothing happend, i try with alert(data); , and the IE no return me. I will block the IE in my website. http://kenogameplay.com